# Permission problem when deploying Cloud Run service to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) User [my@email.com] does not have permission to access namespaces instance [my-project] (or it may not exist): Google Cloud Run Service Agent does not have permission to get access tokens for the service account 112233445566-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Please give service-112233445566@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com permission iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken on the service account. Alternatively, if the service account is unspecified or in the same project you are deploying in, ensure that the Service Agent is assigned the Google Cloud Run Service Agent role roles/run.serviceAgent.

For a non-GCP savvy, what should I enable exactly? I added `Access Creator Token` to all relevant service accounts and it didn't help. I followed all suggestions from other similar questions and nothing worked.

How come it's so complex to enable something like that?

Thank you

Comment: Please continue reading after "alternatively" ...which may be the case.

Comment: If I go to IAM -> Roles -> Cloud Run Service Agent and click "Edit" I can see the "Cloud Run Service Agent" role there.

Comment: Are you following any official documentation or tutorial? I found this documentation detailing the [permissions required](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#required_iam_permissions)

Comment: Can you add "Service account user" and have another try?